# Was a young goat a reasonable price for the service of a prostitute?

Tags: genesis

> Genesis 38:15 When Judah saw her, he thought she was a prostitute, for
> she had covered her face. 16 Not realizing that she was his
> daughter-in-law, he went over to her by the roadside and said, “Come
> now, let me sleep with you.”
>
> “And what will you give me to sleep with you?” she asked.
>
> 17 “I’ll send you a young goat from my flock,” he said.

At this time, was a young goat a reasonable price for the service of a prostitute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benson's commentary offers this -

> Genesis 38:17-21. A kid from the flock — A goodly price at which her
> chastity and honour were valued! Had the consideration been a thousand
> rams, and ten thousands of rivers of oil, it had not been a valuable
> consideration. The favour of God, the purity of the soul, the peace of
> the conscience, and the hope of heaven, are too precious to be exposed
> to sale at any such rates. It is a good account, if it be but true, of
> any place, that which they here gave, that there is no harlot in this
> place, for such sinners are the scandals and plagues of any place.
> Judah sits down content to lose his signet and his bracelets, and
> forbids his friend to make any further inquiry.

However, Ellicott offers another motivation:

> (15) Because she had covered her face.—The Jewish commentators all
> agree that this was not the custom of harlots; and as Judah, in
> Genesis 38:21, calls her kedeshah, one consecrated, he probably
> thought that she was a woman performing the vow required of every
> female votary of the Phœnician Venus (Astarte), once in her lifetime
> (Herod. i. 199). Hence the hire was a kid to be sacrificed to the
> goddess.

This is confirmed by V21 -

> He asked the men of that place, “Where is the shrine prostitute who
> was beside the road at Enaim?”

Comment: could you clarify Herod. i. 199? I have read this claim from time to time and am trying to ascertain its veracity.  + 1

Comment: @DanFefferman - I do not know about Ellicott's reference - that is exactly as I copied it from the standard source at https://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/38-15.htm

Comment: I was able to find it now... Herodotus Book 1 Ch. 199... 'The foulest Babylonian custom is that which compels every woman of the land to sit in the temple of Aphrodite and have intercourse with some stranger once in her life. Many women who are rich and proud and disdain to mingle with the rest, drive to the temple in covered carriages drawn by teams, and stand there with a great retinue of attendants.'https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D199%3Asection%3D1

Comment: @DanFefferman - Ah!! Well done, great work!

Comment: Tamar's case may have been a local variant on this custom.